# slide elements after using remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, transition

Say I had a bunch of boxes tiled up on the screen:

> [1] [2] [3]
>   [4] [5] [6]
>   [7] [8] [9]

each box representing a div.  If I were to use jquery's `.remove()` on one of those divs, how do I make the boxes that come after it slide?

For example, if I removed `box 5`, I would want `box 6` to slide to `box 5`'s place, `box 7` to slide up to `box 6`'s place, and so on.

Currently when I remove a box, the boxes just instantly goes to the desired position. I tried a css3 transition property on them, but it didn't work for some reason.

JS:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); //this will remove the desired box
```

CSS:

```
.left-col-box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 218px;
  height: 218px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;

 -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
-moz-transition: 0.2s;
-ms-transition: 0.2s;
-o-transition: 0.2s;
transition: 0.2s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left-col-box">
  <div class="left-col-box-header">
    <?php echo $rows[1]; ?>
  </div>
  <img src="includes/thumber.php?file=../img/<?php echo $rows2[0]. '.'.$rows2[1];?>&width=217&height=217" />
</div>
```

Please excuse the php.  Thanks!  Basically the HTML and the CSS makes a box.  And I use php to generate x amount of boxes.  If I were to delete one, I'd like them to slide in their desired position.

Comment: post the code that didn't work, so we can help better.

Comment: After removing the one div re-call the code which generates above structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you ok to use a plugin? If so, you can do this easily with [jquery isotape](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Activate the plugin on your container element;

```
$('.parent').isotope({
  itemSelector : '.x'
});
```

and do a reLayout when you delete a box, by calling

```
$('.parent').isotope( 'reLayout');
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2kgU/1/)

Comment: hmm. I didn't see any sliding at all with the fiddle.  it just blinks into position.  do you mind double checking it?

Comment: Oh, you were probably checking it from Chrome, and it was lacking -webkit version of transition property in CSS. I added it, so now it's also working in Chrome. Check the link again.

Comment: perfect perfect.  I'll give you the check :).  Thank you